# How to run fade effect of owl carousel slider in IE browser

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I tried this code it is running perfect on all browser but not on IE anyone help me to resolve this. I can't change this code but please add more code for running fade effect on IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#img-slider").owlCarousel({

    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds

    items : 1,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,1],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [979,1],
    itemsTablet:[768,1],
    navigation : false,
    pagination: true,
    autoPlay: true,
    touchDrag: false,
    mouseDrag: false,
    transitionStyle : "fade"

    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was reported apparently on the plugin's github repo - https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/346

The problem is that owl plugin includes IE10 and 11 among the browsers that don't support CSS transform. So you can use owl carousel in combination with Modernizr and replace the "support3d" variable:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

with

```
support3d = (Modernizr.csstransforms3d);
```

that seems to solve it! :)

Or if you can upgrade the version simply use [this version of](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/index.html) the plugin (pull-request) fixed it.

Comment: No it's not working when i replace this code my slider is not working on any browser please share some other code.

Comment: this is working in my ie browser..well you are using old version i suggest you to upgrade it

Comment: When i replace your code it will be going on top of browser slider not working

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: version IE 10 browser

Comment: version of owl-carousel dude?

Comment: Latest owl-carousel 2

Comment: can u share your file of owl-carousel?

Comment: It's as it is in IE 11 also i checked

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);